# set limit in frontend order's page

Tags: magento-1.9

Tell me how I can do the following: I need to make a drop-down list on the orders page with the order quantity limitations. Now the last 10 orders are displayed by default. I have recently been working with MAGENTO and I can not find where I need to complete the code for my task. 
Here's what I found: file

`\src\app\code\local\My_Project\Sales\Block\Order\History.php`

```
class Eurosouvenir_Sales_Block_Order_History extends Mage_Sales_Block_Order_History
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->getOrders()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());    
    }    
}
```

but any attempts to add a limit here either do not give anything or lead to an error of 500

Comment: I really need help!

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. inserted `echo $this->getPagerHtml();` and it worked

Comment: I would suggest looking at the getOrders() function to actually be able to set your limit.